# Formula to select row cells starting from a certain cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to include in a formula the sum of the values of a row, but starting from a certain cell onto the rest of the row?

Something like `=SUM(C5:~)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula's cell range generally has two parts. A5:H5 contains the cells starting at A5 and includes all cells going across row 5 to H5. Similarly, A5:A9 contains the cells starting at A5 and includes all cells going down the column to A9.

You can use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to determine the second part of the cell range reference.

```
'from A5 to the last number or date in row 5
=A5:INDEX(5:5, match(1e99, 5:5))
'from A5 to the last text in row 5
=A5:INDEX(5:5, match("zzz", 5:5))

'from A5 to the last number or date in column A
=A5:INDEX(A:A, match(1e99, A:A))
'from A5 to the last text in column A
=A5:INDEX(A:A, match("zzz", A:A))
```

To [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) from D5 to the last number in row 5,

```
=SUM(D5:INDEX(5:5, match(1e99, 5:5)))
```

This method is preferred when creating dynamic named ranged (with formulas as the Refers to:) over the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) as INDEX is non-volatile while OFFSET is volatile and will recalculate whenever anything in your workbook changes.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
=SUM(5:5)-SUM(A5:B5)
```

as would

```
=SUM(C5:XFD5)
```

as XFD (16384) corresponds to the [maximum number of columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: You're thinking in columns, he wants to sum on rows.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @DavidGM

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(C5:XFD5)
```

Tested and it works. The last column is XFD, so you're summing on everything right of C5.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

=SUM(E3:E)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M1gS.jpg)
so the result will be 6, as you starter from
certain cell.

Comment: A similar answer is previously given by someone else on this post. If your answer is different, mention how it is different.